# API Response is 200 ok when using HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)

Tags: api, asp.net-core

I was using the following class in my API and it appears that returning BadRequest does not return a BadRequest in the actual response. Only in the content of the message. How to make it return 400 in the "correct" place?

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace KardexAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: PostMan response]

I solved this personally by switching to

```
IActionResult
```

instead of

```
HttpResponseMessage
```

And then

```
return BadRequest();
```

But I am still curious how to solve the above issue.

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't have special processing for `HttpResponseMessage`. If you return that from an action, it's just a regular object that gets serialised using JSON etc. It's just something that changed between the versions. The solution you show is correct.

Comment: @KirkLarkin interesting, thanks.